# Artifactory ignores checksum uploads on maven-metadata.xml files

Tags: maven-3, artifactory

I have a large Maven repository, hosted by Artifactory version 5.4.6.
Using the JFrog REST API, I can look at all the bad or missing checksums with

```
curl -u "admin:$PASSWORD" -X GET "http://myserver/artifactory/api/search/badChecksum?type=sha1&repos=mymavenrepo"
```

This returns surprisingly a lot of errors about "missing client checksums" for all my "maven-metadata.xml" files.

However I deploy all the files in the repo using maven plugins that do publish checksums. And when I deploy new files, I can see in *logs/request.log* that

- the existing *maven-metadata.xml* is downloaded (GET on maven-metadata.xml)
- the updated *maven-metadata.xml* is uploaded (PUT on maven-metadata.xml)
- the MD5 hash for the updated *maven-metadata.xml* is uploaded (PUT on maven-metadata.xml.md5)
- the SHA1 hash for the updated *maven-metadata.xml* is uploaded (PUT on maven-metadata.xml.sha1)

Doing some tests on the CLI, I can confirm that PUT calls to set checksums work on normal files, but are simply ignored on *maven-metadata.xml* files.

For a standard JAR

```
FAKE_SHA1=0000111122223333444455556666777788889999
curl -u "admin:$PASSWORD" -X PUT "http://myserver/artifactory/mymavenrepo/javax/mail/mail/1.4.3/mail-1.4.3.jar.sha1" --data-ascii "$FAKE_SHA1"
```

will return the following errors

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 409,
    "message" : "Checksum error for 'javax/mail/mail/1.4.3/mail-1.4.3.jar.sha1': received '0000111122223333444455556666777788889999' but actual is '8154bf8d666e6db154c548dc31a8d512c273f5ee'"
  } ]
}
```

For a maven-metada.xml file

```
FAKE_SHA1=0000111122223333444455556666777788889999
curl -u "admin:$PASSWORD" -X PUT "http://myserver/artifactory/mymavenrepo/javax/mail/mail/maven-metadata.xml.sha1" --data-ascii "$FAKE_SHA1"
```

will return absolutely nothing

And now, launching badChecksum will complain that the JAR has a wrong client checksum, but will keep complaining that the maven metadata has no client checksum:

```
curl -u "admin:$PASSWORD" -X GET "http://myserver/artifactory/api/search/badChecksum?type=sha1&repos=mymavenrepo" | grep "javax/mail" -A2
```

returns

```
    "uri" : "http://myserver/artifactory/api/storage/mymavenrepo/javax/mail/mail/maven-metadata.xml",
    "serverSha1" : "61001c349ebaac8e116d5f25716e2abf31e081af",
    "clientSha1" : ""
--
    "uri" : "http://myserver/artifactory/api/storage/mymavenrepo/javax/mail/mail/1.4.3/mail-1.4.3.jar",
    "serverSha1" : "8154bf8d666e6db154c548dc31a8d512c273f5ee",
    "clientSha1" : "0000111122223333444455556666777788889999"
```

Is there any reason for *maven-metadata.xml* files to have weird checksum semantics? 
This basically breaks the badChecksum REST feature for me, as legitimate errors are flooded by these metadata errors.

My point of view is that either *maven-metadata.xml* files are special and badChecksum should ignore them, or they act like normal files, and client checksums should be recorded...

The only workaround I see is to use the *fixChecksum* API but then you simply accept the server checksum rather than push the local checksum...

```
curl -u "admin:$PASSWORD" -X POST "http://myserver/artifactory/api/checksums/fix" --data-ascii "{\"repoKey\":\"mymavenrepo\",\"path\":\"javax/mail/mail/maven-metadata.xml\"}" --header "Content-Type: application/json"
{"info":"Successfully fixed checksum inconsistency"}
```

Comment: I would be happy to get a comment explaining the downvote. I think missing client checksums is annoying for a lot of people. If I am missing something obvious, I would like to know...

Comment: maven-metadata.xml is auto-generated by Artifactory based on the contents of adjacent folders, why do you want to set checksums for it..?

Comment: if you are using the maven command line to deploy artifacts, maven will *itself* download the existing maven-metadata.xml and reupload it afterwards.
AFAICS, this logic is in the **org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer** class in maven-artifact-transfer.
You can do the following test from a standard maven project:
`mvn clean install deploy:deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=test::default::http://myserver/artifactory/mymavenrepo`
You will see in the logs that the deploy plugin downloads the metadata first, and reuploads it last.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem in Intellij when I try to publish modules to a Maven repository, hosted by Artifactory, using the JFrog REST API. The problem is: apparently (by what the logs say), the regular [Deploy Apache Maven Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) sends a file `.sh1` or `.md5` along with the module, e.g., a `.jar` file, but the [JFrog REST API expects a HTTP header](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-are-client-checksum-server-checksum-and-checksum-policy-in-local-repositories/) with the `sha1` or `md5` value, not a file.

The solution I found: using the [Maven Artifactory Plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin). It deals with this part (apparently it deals, because the error has gone, but I didn't look whats is going on under the hood).